# Uso delle particelle pronominali in frasi col verbo essere

Tags: grammar, verbs, pronouns

Stavo discutendo oggi riguardo una canzoncina svedese per bambini, che fa

> En kulen natt, natt, natt
>   min båt jag styrde
>   på havets vågade, vågade våg
>   så skummet yrde.
>   Och vart jag sågade, sågade, såg
>   på havets vågade, vågade, våg
>   långt ner i djupetti, petti, pe
>   en fisk jag såg, och det var du...

Mi è stato detto che le ultime due frasi si traducono in italiano, letteralmente, con

> ho visto un pesce, e questo era tu

Ora, il punto della discussione è stato: nella frase finale il soggetto è "questo", predicato è il verbo essere alla terza persona e complemento oggetto è il "tu".
Sia in italiano che in svedese però esiste una particella apposita per i complementi: te/dej.
In italiano frasi simili si pongono sempre con soggetto la seconda persona, e la traduzione non letterale sarebbe quindi

> ho visto un pesce, ed eri tu

Questa traduzione aggira il problema, perciò la domanda resta: quale frase è corretta?

Sia "questo era tu" che "questo era te" suonano così strane, ma suppongo esista una forma corretta per usare il verbo essere alla terza persona con complemento una seconda persona.

Comment: Ma nella frase “questo era tu”, “tu” non è un complemento oggetto. “Essere” non è un verbo transitivo. (In “Io sono Daniele”, “Daniele” non è un oggetto, mica sto dicendo che mangio, o amo Daniele.) “Ho visto un pesce, ed eri tu” mi sembra l'unica traduzione possibile, fra quelle proposte; non è che si aggiri il problema, è che “questo era tu/te” non è italiano.

Comment: Evidentemente mi sono perso nell'analisi della frase: visto che "tu" non è il complemento oggetto, che ruolo copre nella frase? Se la ribaltiamo "tu eri il pesce" , il pesce cos'è?

Comment: _Il pesce_ nel tuo esempio è una parte del predicato nominale (_eri il pesce_) che si chiama "nome del predicato". L'altra parte (_eri_) si chiama "copula". Il verbo essere (e altri verbi quando sono usati in senso simile) non è come gli altri.

Comment: @MauroVanetti mi ha risparmiato la fatica di rispondere. :-) Aggiungo, per chi ha un'infarinatura di latino (anche se i confronti tra fenomeni simili in lingue diverse vanno sempre presi con un granello di sale), che lì la differenza tra complemento oggetto e nome del predicato è particolarmente evidente, perché il primo si esprime con un accusativo (“si vis *pacem* para *bellum*”), mentre il secondo con un nominativo (“tu es *Petrus*”).

Comment: Ben detto @DaG, del resto _tu_ / _te_ sono proprio il nominativo e l'accusativo di _tu_ in latino, arrivati pari pari in italiano. Le forme diverse dei pronomi personali secondo la funzione grammaticale sono proprio gli unici residui in italiano (come in altre lingue romanze) dei casi latini.

Comment: "Io sono Te" è il titolo di una canzone abbastanza nota, non ho sentito molti protestare; mi pare che qui l'italiano faccia un'eccezione.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La traduzione proposta inizialmente è inequivocabilmente sbagliata:

> Ho visto un pesce, e questo era tu.

A parte l'uso insolito di "questo" (sembra un anglicismo), le uniche traduzioni giuste prevedono che si usi la seconda persona singolare, per esempio:

> Ho visto un pesce, e il pesce eri tu.

Grammaticalmente il soggetto è *tu* e per questo il verbo si coniuga così. Non è proprio la stessa cosa dire *tu sei il pesce* oppure dire *il pesce sei tu*, ma se per indicare l'enfasi si usa l'ordine delle parole grammaticalmente *tu* assorbe sempre il predicato, così come farebbero *io*, *noi* o *voi*. Si tratta di una anomalia, probabilmente dovuta soltanto al fatto che sentire *...era tu* o *...è io* suscita un senso di errore di coniugazione anche quando a logica dovrebbero essere ammissibili, ma una lingua viva non funziona a logica.

Un caso interessante, che dimostra che il problema è proprio evitare quella discordanza apparente, è

> Tu sei me.

Si usa questa espressione, che non ha senso perché il verbo essere non è transitivo e quindi non vuole complemento oggetto, pur di evitare entrambe le inascoltabili alternative:

> Tu sei io.
>
> Tu sono io.

Scegliere fra questi due orrori sarebbe impossibile e si adotta la soluzione che taglia la testa al toro, pur sacrificando la razionalità grammaticale.

Dove non c'è via di scampo si cede e si sceglie a caso:

> Voi siete noi.
>
> Noi siamo voi.
>
> Voi siamo noi.
>
> Noi siete voi.

Comment: è una buona risposta, grazie, ma ci sono delle parti che non mi convincono moltissimo ancora. Il "tu sei me" e "io sono te" sono scorretti, ma usati, c'è qualche fonte autorevole che ne dichiara l'anomala correttezza?

Comment: Hmm... Non li definirei "scorretti ma utilizzati": sono l'unico modo per dire quella frase in italiano, il che vuol dire che sono un'eccezione o qualcosa del genere, ma giusti. Diresti forse _tu sei io_?

Comment: Comunque ecco un fatto interessante: online non trovo niente su _tu sei me_. Niente niente.

Comment: Scrive Serianni (VII.10): «Talvolta si usano le forme oblique *me* e *te* anche in funzione di soggetto:  
...  
*c*) Quando hanno funzione predicativa e il soggetto è diverso: “io non sono te”, “uno che [...] vuole esser me in ogni cosa” (Caro, *Lettere familiari*); se il soggetto è lo stesso i pronomi restano *io* e *tu*: “se io non fossi io, cioè il poeta (come mi chiamano) della democrazia” (Carducci, *Prose*, 869-870).  
...»

Comment: Bel colpo! L'esempio _io sono io_ mi sembra confermare proprio quello che pensavo: questa eccezione serve proprio a evitare le brutture _sono tu_ e _sei io_ ecc. che il nostro orecchio rifiuta perché li prende per errori di coniugazione. Con _io sono io_ la bruttura non c'è e quindi tutti contenti.

Answer (score 0):

La frase *"questo era tu"* è decisamente sbagliata: innanzi tutto il pronome da usare è *te* e non *tu* in quanto il soggetto del predicato nominale è il pesce.
Quando il predicato nominale indica una relazione di identità, inoltre, si preferisce sempre usare la prima e la seconda persona invece della terza; dato che questa relazione è simmetrica, sul piano logico non ci sono differenze.
Io sono quel pesce oppure quel pesce sono io, invece di quel pesce è me.
Tu sei quel pesce o quel pesce sei tu, invece di quel pesce è te.
Dunque direi che è melgio tradurre: *"e quel pesce eri tu" "e quello eri tu"* oppure *"ed eri tu"*. L'ultima traduzione è senz'altro migliore anche dal punto di vista musicale.

Comment: Fermi tutti: qui abbiamo il verbo essere quindi non c'è nessun complemento. _Io sono Mauro_ = soggetto (_io_) + predicato nominale (_sono Mauro_). Predicato nominale = copula (_sono_) + nome del predicato (_Mauro_).

Comment: @MauroVanetti grazie per avere segnalato l'errore, correggo la risposta, anche se ormai mi sono meritato un voto negativo!

Comment: Ma i voti cambiano... ;-)